# Retrieving object data from multiple tables help

Tags: sql, database, orm, ibatis

Sorry if I'm not wording this too well, but let me try to explain what I'm doing. I have a main object of class A, that has multiple objects of classes B, C, D and E.

such that:

```
Class ObjectA
{
     ObjectB[] myObjectBs;
     ObjectC[] myObjectCs;
     ObjectD[] myObjectDs;
     ObjectE[] myObjectEs;
 }
```

where A---B mapping is 1 to many, for B, C, D and E. That is, all B,C,D,E objects are associated with only one object A.

I'm storing the data for all these objects in a database, with Table A holding all the data for the instances of Class A, etc.

Now, when getting the data for this at run time on the fly, I'm running 5 different queries for each object.

(very simplified psuedocode)

```
objectA=sql("select * from tableA where id=#id#");
objectA.setObjectBs(sql("select * from tableB where a_id=#id#");
objectA.setObjectCs(sql("select * from tableC where a_id=#id#");
objectA.setObjectDs(sql("select * from tableD where a_id=#id#");
objectA.setObjectEs(sql("select * from tableE where a_id=#id#");
```

if that makes sense.

Now, I'm wondering, is this the most efficient way of doing it? I feel like there should be a way to get all this info in 1 query, but doing something like "select * from a,b,c,d,e where a.id = #id# and b.a_id = #id# and c.a_id = #id# and d.a_id = #id# and e.a_id = #id#" will give a result set with all the columns of A,B,C,D,E for each row, and there will be many many more rows that I'd be needing.

If there was only one array of objects (like just ObjectBs) it could be done with a simple join and then handled by my database framework. If the relationships were A(one)....B(many) and B(one)....C(many) it could be done with two joins and work. But for A(one)....B(many) and A(one)....C(many) etc I can't think of a good way to do joins or return this data without having too many rows, as with joins if A has 10 Bs and 10Cs, it'll return 100 rows rather than 20.

So, is the way I'm currently doing it, with 5 different selects, the most efficient (which it seems like its not), or is there a better way of doing it?

Also, If  I were to grab a large set of these at once (say, 5000 ObjectAs and all the associated Bs, Cs, Ds, and Es), would there be a way to do it without running a ton of consecutive queries one after the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can try iBatis using N+1 Select Lists

http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s05.html

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge performance issue with N+1 selects (check https://github.com/balak1986/prime-cache-support-in-ibatis2/blob/master/README). So please don't use it unless there is no other way of achieving this.

Luckily iBatis has groupBy property, that is created exactly to map data for these kind of complex object. 
Check the example from http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/06/ibatis-tutorial-aggregation-with.html